# Use String Value as a Variable Name in C#

Tags: c#, sql, razor-pages

I have a string that is being passed to my controller in Razor Pages. This string contains the name of one of 8 possible Booleans as selected by the user. I am attempting to use this Boolean Name in a SQL server query as shown below.

```
try
{
     var test = await _context.GuestModel
     .Include(r => r.PatientModel)
     .OrderByDescending(r => r.GuestLastName)
     .Where(r => r.booleanName  == true)
     .ToListAsync();
     return test;
}
```

booleanName is the string containing the Boolean Name I need to use, but so far I have not been able to access that information successfully.

Comment: You can't just do that in a straightforward manner.  You'll either have to build up the expression tree yourself using reflection, or use a library such as [DynamicLinq](https://dynamic-linq.net/) to do that for you.

Comment: At some point, you are going to have to translate what the Razor page calls the property and what the database calls the field.   They shouldn't (have to) be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `switch` or `if/else` blocks to pick from one of eight possible versions of the query based on the string.

Comment: Yeah I am leaning this way, and it will definitely work. Was just interested to learn if there was a cleaner way.

Comment: @WreckingCrew `Dictionary<string, Func>` might look cleaner.